# Bing Map view in modern sites?

Tags: list-view, map

SharePoint Online has a location column that allows you to enter an entire address. Really helpful column. If your list has this column, you can create a view for that list that is a Bing Map. The actually map displays correctly when viewing it in classic mode but not when viewing it in modern. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this or it will be available in the future?